# How do I delete a post in hexo

Tags: hexo

I am using  to write my blog, I meet a trouble that I can not delete a post in  blog. I just find create a post in command, but I could not find the delete or drop command. How can I delete a post in  properly? What command should I use?

In addition, I push the  blog to  page. When I delete a post, can the  page be changed?

Answer (score 32):

There is no command to delete a post on Hexo, but follow this steps :
1. Delete the post under `source/_post` folder
2. Run `hexo clean` to delete the database (`db.json`) and `assets` folder
3. Run `hexo generate`to generate the new blog without your deleted post
4. Run `hexo deploy` to deploy your blog

Alternatively you can use the [hexo-admin](https://github.com/jaredly/hexo-admin) plugin.

Comment: make sure to scan the `public` folder for anything that should not be there before running `clean`. Someone may have stored assets there which will be deleted by `clean`

Answer (score 2):

You can just go to your hexo path/source/_posts, delete the one you wanna delete.

Then run

```
hexo generate

hexo deploy
```

you will see that one has gone from your blog site.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the files under source/_post folder.

For question 2. It depends on which repo you are using.